# Material in material preview window becomes pale

Tags: materials

Good day. My "blush" in material preview window becomes pale, I need it with the same color as it's displayed in solid window with alpha blend. I'm embedding screenshot from shader editor with material settings. How can I fix it?

material preview window

[image]

solid window

[image]

shader editor
[image]

blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mgDzZq4uhJx0obLe9iVUwuW2AJi4Z9Je/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: @Chris  I have attached the file above

Answer (score 0):

i would propose you change your shader nodes like this:

[image]

Don't use the transparent BSDF but the color for the first shader.

I just hope you don't need this transparency...

result in material preview:

[image]